# Listen DOM change on hover element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, hover, mutation-observers

I need to check if element on hover do something, if yes get it, if not return.

button -> mouseover event -> DOM change ? return element : not return.

How can i do it?
all I came up with was to use MutationObserver. But I still haven't figured out how :(

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need [a `mouseover` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, but if element don't do anything on hover?

Comment: It's impossible to help without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: try this:
`$('element').on('mouseover', () => {/*your code*/});`